# Maven checkstyle plugin: Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am trying to configure checkstyle plugin with gradle (in a java 11) project as follows:

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '8.2'
    configFile = rootProject.file('config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
    configProperties = [
            'checkstyle.cache.file': "${buildDir}/checkstyle.cache",
    ]
    ignoreFailures = true
    showViolations = true
}
```

My checkstyle.xml is like as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<code_scheme name="CustomStyle" version="1">
  <AndroidXmlCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="USE_CUSTOM_SETTINGS" value="true"/>
    <option name="LAYOUT_SETTINGS">
      <value>
        <option name="INSERT_BLANK_LINE_BEFORE_TAG" value="false"/>
      </value>
    </option>
```

......

And I am getting the below exception

> Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: unable to
>   parse configuration stream - Document is invalid: no grammar
>   found.:3:13
>               at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:441)
>               at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:386)
>               at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ant.CheckstyleAntTask.createRootModule(CheckstyleAntTask.java:407)
>               ... 106 more
>       Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/workspace/service/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml;
>   lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 13; Document is invalid: no grammar
>   found.

Any pointers to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My checkstyle.xml is like as follows:
>   `<code_scheme name="CustomStyle" version="1">`

This not the correct markup for checkstyle. Checkstyle configurations are like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
    </module>
</module>
```

You can read https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config.html for more information.

It looks like what you have given it was an IntelliJ configuration file. Either way, it is not compatible with checkstyle.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define what to check against; for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
```

which should be one of [these .dtd files](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/tree/master/src/main/resources/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle).

Comment: Mine doesn’t seems to fit against any of the dtds mentioned in the link ... IntelliJ recognises it as a valid checkstyle however

Comment: I checked google checkstyle which also follow the same syntax... does this mean. In order to use maven check style gotta stick with specific syntax ?